# Splicing an Object from within an Object (JavaScript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, javascript-objects

What is a method I can use to splice an object from within an object.
I have an Object called `Bullets`. Inside of the there is the users ID, ('User1'). Inside of the User1 Object, is all the bullets that they have fired.
(I am using Firebase to make a multiplayer game, that's why their is an ID for every player)

```
Bullets -> User1 -> bullet0: [x: 200, y: 200, vx: 10, vy: 1]
                 -> bullet1: [x: 200, y: 300, vx: 10, vy: 1]
        
        -> User2 -> bullet0: [x: 50, y: 10, vx: 10, vy: 1]
                 -> bullet1: [x: 500, y: 20, vx: 10, vy: 1]`
                
        etc.
```

I am making it so that when a bullet goes out of range, it will be spliced from the `bullets` Object to help with framerate.
How can I **completely** delete/splice/remove the fired `bullet0` from the Object?

This is the code i have tried so far...

```
bullets.User1.bullet0 = Object.entries(bullets.User1.bullet0).splice()
```

All this did was set both the X & Y properties to be `NaN`. Might be worth noting that it managed to delete the `vx` & `vy` properties from it as well, with no trace.

The idea that was meant to happen is that the entire `bullet0` Object would get deleted, So then the diagram mentioned earlier would look like this:

```
Bullets -> User1 -> bullet1: [x: 200, y: 300, vx: 10, vy: 1]
```

(Same Diagram as before but without `bullet0`).

I'm open to suggestions. I have been working on this for a while and i cant find a fix. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `delete bullets.User1.bullet0`

Comment: @Barmar . I cant believe it was that simple all along. Thank you